# The Message-Driven EJB unable to connect JMS Destination stating Error creating the db_connection

Tags: oracle, jms, ejb, datasource, advanced-queuing

we have Oracle OSB 11g which is connecting to Oracle 12C DB in remote location or a different LAN.

THE WebLogic EJBs connecting to Oracle AQs via JMS/JDBC and currently we are having issues with them.

the WLS logs says:

```
####<Sep 21, 2018 9:15:51.083 AM GMT+00:00> <Warning> <EJB> <10.170.128.102> 
<osb02_m1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default 
(self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> 
<e10b4740d6c6fa2e:-5f6b2f84:165f9d83f34:-8000-0000000000000f87> 
<1537521351083> <BEA-010096> <The Message-Driven EJB: 
RequestEJB3103778799539238415X86e7f92.165e6e1ae31.X725d is unable to connect 
to the JMS destination or bind to JCA resource adapter: queue/ProvRequestAQ. 
Connection failed after 2,609 attempts. The MDB will attempt to 
reconnect/rebind every 10 seconds. This log message will repeat every 600 
seconds until the condition clears.>

####<Sep 21, 2018 9:15:51.083 AM GMT+00:00> <Warning> <EJB> <10.170.128.102> 
<osb02_m1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default 
(self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> 
<e10b4740d6c6fa2e:-5f6b2f84:165f9d83f34:-8000-0000000000000f87> 
<1537521351083> <BEA-010061> <The Message-Driven EJB: 
RequestEJB3103778799539238415X86e7f92.165e6e1ae31.X725d is unable to connect 
to the JMS destination: queue/ProvRequestAQ. The Error was:
oracle.jms.AQjmsException: Error creating the db_connection
Nested exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Remote JDBC 
disabled
Nested exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Remote JDBC 
disabled>
```

I searched in internet and found the solution that I have to add the below parameter and add to setDomainEnv.sh and restart the WebLogic admins and managed servers, but still this issue is not resolved. I also checked that the DB User used to connect the DB has enqueue/dequeue privileges over the Oracle queues.

Parameter was

```
WLS_JDBC_REMOTE_ENABLED="-Dweblogic.jdbc.remoteEnabled=true"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the parameter must be added to the startup parameters of your managed servers from your domain console. After adding the parameter restart your managed servers.

The requested parameter might give some trouble on weblogic 12.1.3. As a matter of fact the parameter is deprecated since weblogic 10.3.6.

If you are still in trouble try the following workaround:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24376/rmidriver.htm#JDBCP350

Might be helpful.